# Cronjob Command / URL Gives Not Found

Tags: cron, cpanel

I'm trying to add a cronjob in cPanel. It's meant for updating the FeedWordpress. The plugin works fine. But the cron job is not.
I set it on Hourly update and the url is: http://example.com/?update_feedwordpress=1

The email I get in the Webmail says:

> /usr/local/cpanel/bin/jailshell: http://example.com/?update_feedwordpress=1: No such file or directory

The thing is, this example.com is hosted inside a main site, and this 'main' site runs the cron jobs. So, my guess is that I have to find the correct path.

What do you think?

Comment: So, what is your suggestion? By the way, this is what boss wants. I have no choice for this task!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cron wants to run commands, but a URL isn't a command.

If you want to get a cron-initiated job to hit that URL, hopefully your system will already have 'curl', so try running :

```
curl "http://example.com/?update_feedwordpress=1"
```